# Inverse problem of interpolation with Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Assume the following equation holds when $x, a, b,c,d$(variables) taking any values:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
r_0&r_1&r_2 \\ s_0&s_1&s_2\\t_0&t_1&t_2
 \end{bmatrix}  
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1 \\ x&2x\\x^2&-x^2
 \end{bmatrix}  =
\begin{bmatrix}
a+b&c+d \\ a-b&c-2d\\a+2b&2c+d
 \end{bmatrix}  
$$
one can get following constraints on $r_i, s_i, r_i$ by substitutions:
$$
\begin{cases}   
2t_0-3r_0+s_0=0\\
2t_1-3r_1+s_1=0\\
2t_2-3r_2+s_2=0\\
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}   
3t_0-5r_0-s_0=0\\
3t_1-5r_1-s_1=0\\
3t_2-5r_2-s_2=0\\
\end{cases}  \\
$$
Thus, the values of $r_i, s_i, r_i$ can be derived by performing pseudoinverse on the matrix equations:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & -3 &1 \\  3 & -5 &-1 
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 t_0 \\  r_0 \\  s_0 
 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\  0 
 \end{bmatrix}\\
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & -3 &1 \\  3 & -5 &-1 
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 t_1 \\  r_1 \\  s_1 
 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\  0 
 \end{bmatrix}   \\
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & -3 &1 \\  3 & -5 &-1 
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 t_2 \\  r_2 \\  s_2 
 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\  0 
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
I feel it's an inverse problem of interpolation with Vandermonde matrix.

Is there a well-defined technique to do the above calculations? The matrix equation involved in my work is actually much bigger, thus I am looking for a systematic way to derive $r_i, r_i, t_i
$ without given any particular values of $x, a, b,c,d$.

Comment: Shouldn't there be exponents ?

Comment: Yes, the first equation is a system of polynomials. I show the case of degree 2.

Comment: I don't see any Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: One of the ways that the Vandermonde matrix appears is that you have a polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_ix^i$, and you are looking to find the coefficients $a_i$ that satisfy $f(b_j)=c_j$ for $j=1,\cdots,n$.  You have some things that are Vandermonde-like, but it's not obvious how a Vandermonde matrix appears.